# How to implement cursor pagination using Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Ive been looking for a way to implement cursor pagination using Sequelize and Postgres, I can't find any clear basic examples as to how to do this. I know that there are npm packages which can help but there doesn't seem to be any clear instruction on how to use them.

Answer (score 3):

I know that I'm a little late, but I was able to implement cursor pagination by doing something like this.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const getUsers = async (lastId, limit) => {
    const cursor = lastId || 0;
    return await User.findAll({
        limit: limit
        where: {
            id: {
                [Op.gt]: cursor
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This presumes Ids are sortable, and sorted in the query

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for that [sequelize-cursor-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cursor-pagination).

Answer (score 0):

sequelize-cursor-pagination. is a quite package for pagination. But it is not good for performance now, because it consumes 3 queries,especially is query used to count all row.

Comment: Commentary like this belongs as a comment to the question or answer it is responding to, rather than as a separate answer. Yes, I know you cannot make comments yet, but there are [reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).